# Basic認証時、specファイルを作成してください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Ruby on Railsで開発をしています。
現在、scaffoldで簡単な管理画面を作成しています。
中身はほぼ終わり、管理画面全体にbasic認証をかけましたが、その後、scaffoldで自動的に生成されてたspecファイルの内容がパスできなくなりました。
Basic認証時にテストをパスさせるために必要なことは何か、コードでわかりやすく教えていただきたいです。
あと、specファイルを書くのが難しいですので、参考できるサイトなどもお勧めしていただければと思います。

以下は現在自分のspecファイルです。

spec/requests/admin_companies_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Admin::Companies', type: :request do
  describe 'GET /admin_companies' do
    it 'works! (now write some real specs)' do
      get companies_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
end
```

必要なファイルとファイルの中身を詳細にお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どのようなコードになっているのかわからないので、的確なアドバイスは出来かねますが、テストのみbasic認証をパスさせるのであれば、環境を見てbasic認証する・しないを判定してはどうでしょうか。特にご自身で修正を加えていなければ、テスト(rake spec)は`RAILS_ENV=test`で動作しているかと思いますので、認証部分は以下のようになるかと思います。

```
def basic_authenticate
  return true Rails.env.test? # testの場合は一律trueを返す

  # test以外の場合はbasic認証を実施する
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user, pass|
    user == 'hoge' && pass == 'foo'
  end
end
```

また、basic認証部分のメソッドを`before_action`で一元的に実行しているのでしたら、以下のような制御も可能かと思います。

```
# test時はbasic_authenticateメソッドを実行しない
before_action :basic_authenticate, if: !Rails.env.test?
```

RSpecの参考資料ですが、**Everyday Rails - RSpecによるRailsテスト入門 (https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec-jp)** という書籍が大変良書ですので、ぜひご一読することをお勧めします。(リファレンスとしても利用できるかと思います)

Comment: Basic認証はかけている状態です。内容を編集してspecファイルのコードを記入しましてのでそれをパスするためのコードを教えてくださいませんか？

Comment: テストは本番コードが通るように書くもので、テストが通るように本番コードに手を入れるのは避けるべきです。このように「テストでは認証を回避」にしてしまうと、認証が通ったこと/通っていないことのテストができず、「認証が必要なactionが認証なしでも実行できる」といったバグが発見できません。

Comment: 特定の環境のみskipさせるという意で記載してしまいましたが、上記コメントで @suzukis さんが仰られている通り、_テストが通るように本番コードに手を入れるのは避けるべき_ ですので、下記で@suzukis さんがアドバイスされている通り、`request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials('user', 'pass')` を利用し、RSpecの`before`メソッドで実行してはいかかでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

英語版に[同じ質問があり回答がついてます](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768718/rails-rspec-make-tests-pass-with-http-basic-authentication/5239091#5239091)

BASIC認証は`HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`ヘッダにBASE64でエンコードした`ユーザー名:パスワードを載せてリクエストを投げるもので、Railsアプリは環境変数からヘッダを読み込みますので、テストでBASIC認証を模倣するには環境変数に然るべき値を設定すればよい、ということです。

```
request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user,pw)
```